# Cannot Uninstall Apache Netbeans 11.2 on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, uninstallation

Exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

java/util/jar/Pack200

[image: Critical Error]

This error occur when I tried to uninstall Apache Netbeans 11.2. I've tried to uninstall it using Windows' "Add and Remove" setting and CCleaner. Both show same error. I've tried look into other stackoverflow questions regarding this issue but their issues are different from mine.

Answer (score 2):

I had JDK 8 installed and then I installed Apache Netbeans 11.3. After
I wanted to update the JDK and uninstall JDK 8 and install JDK 16. Then
I wanted to update Netbeans and I tried to uninstall Netbeans 11.3, but I
couldn't, I got the same error mentioned above, fix it as follows

1.- Uninstall the JDK 16

2.- Install the JDK 8 again

3.- Uninstall Netbeans 11.3 (this time I got it)

Comment: You could explain the timeline better.  It is confusing whether Netbeans 11 was uninstalled as a cascading ramification of uninstalling jdk 16 (or whether you overtly uninstalled Netbeans 11 too).   I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review because you are a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer into an excellent one.

Comment: Hello Andreas, I did modified the text, I hope it is clearer